# How to override react component with predefined properties?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm developing [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) app and want to predefine styles for header in `Scene` component (From `react-native-router-flux`)

Here is my `modalScene.js`

```
export default class ModalScene extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Scene
        key={ this.props.key }
        direction={ this.props.key || 'vertical'}
        hideNavBar={ false }
        duration={ 0 }
        component={ this.props.component }
        navigationBarStyle={{
          backgroundColor: global.color.superWhite,
          paddingTop: 18,
          paddingBottom: 0,
          height: 100
        }}
        backButtonTextStyle={{
          paddingLeft: 10,
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: 20,
          lineHeight: 22,
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }}
        backTitle={ this.props.backTitle }
        backButtonImage={ require('../../assets/img/icons/backButton.png') }
        {...this.props}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

When i'm using in `Router`

```
<ModalScene
  key='signup'
  component={ SignupScreen }
  backTitle='Вход'
/>
```

It's not working. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any testable repo with the gist of your problem?

Comment: @Alberto no, i haven't